# How to get Runtime 3.0 for Business central CU 10 (August 2019 release)

Tags: runtime, upgrade, dynamics-business-central

My infrastructure guy just install the new BC with CU 10 (August 2019), I double-checked and its runtime is 2.4
I even get the below error when I try to install an extension with Runtime 3.0:

```
The runtime version of the extension package is currently set to '3.0'. The runtime version must be set to '2.4' or earlier in the app.json file in order to install the extension package on this platform.
```

based on this link, if I'm on CU10 then it should give me the runtime 3.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-json-files

Does anyone have any idea how to get the runtime 3.0 on business central on-perm?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a detailed list of Business Central versions:

https://www.navisionplanet.com/business-central-download-version-list/#BC15

It's an annoying website that jumps to ads once in a while! Find your version and upgrade one generation, I think 14.1 is the first version with Runtime 3.